# How to identify which cell has the minimum value in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I currently have the following cell :

G=cell(4,2)

Each sell has a `2x1 double`

Example :

```
[100;200]   [20;60]
[100;300]   [20;90]
[200;300]   [60;90]
[]  []      []  []
```

How can I identify which cell has the minimum value, (where the values compared are in the SECOND column) so that the addition is between 20;60 20;90 and 60;90 ?

I started typing out a code but got stuck :

```
for k=1:(4)
    add(k)=sum(cell2mat(G(k+4)))
end

(...Find a way to know which cell gave the minimum off `add` using min(add)...)
```

But then I don't how to identify which cell  has the minimum .. The answer I'm looking for should indicate that the minimum value is at **Column 2 Row 1 of cell G** and hence : 20;60

Comment: you should also specify what you define as a minimum in the array. A vector-minimum? A min per dimension (i.e. each row in each cell entry?).

Comment: @gevang The minimum I want is the minimum sum value of both values in each cell in the second column. As in 20;60, cell 5 is the min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`G[{:}]` will arrange (column-wise) the cell array to a 2D matrix (lines corresponding to the first and second element of each cell entry

```
ans =

   100   100   200    20    20    60
   200   300   300    60    90    90
```

You can then apply `min` accordingly to obtain the minimum value and a linear index on the cell, e.g.:

```
[minVal, minIndex] = min([G{:}], [], 2);
```

**Update:** Since the sum of elements is defined as minimum (L1 norm), you can use [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to detect empty entries and sum in each, before applying `min` over the resulting array:

```
indexEmpty = cellfun(@isempty, G)  % find empty entries of G
sumG = cellfun(@sum, G)            % apply sum on each entry of G 
sumG(indexEmpty) = nan;            % set empty entries to NaN (exclude from min) 
[minVal, minIndex] = min(sumG(:)); % return min and its location in sumG (and G)
```

Result: `G{minIndex}`

```
ans =

   20
   60
```

The linear index `minIndex` can be translated to array subscripts using [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html).

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(G), minIndex);
```

In this way you can index the array both using `G{minIndex}` (i.e., 5) and `G{i,j}` (i.e., 1,2).

Comment: @NLed minVal is the minimum (as you define it). You can convert 4 (a linear index) to row and column using a simple formula or `ind2sub` using the dimensions of the non-empty entry array, i.e. [i,j] = ind2sub([3,2],4).

Comment: @NLed see my updated answer that handles your definition of min and the empty cell-array values.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to the code ? Would love to learn this rather than just copy it ... Also, how can I indicate which cell number is the minimum at ? For example, `cell [1,2]` for 20;60, and `cell [1,1]` for 100;200 ?

Comment: @NLed you can look into cellfun, which is very practical for applying functions at each entry of the array. Also, as I said above, you can convert a linear index using function `ind2sub().` For the case here `[i,j] = ind2sub(size(G), minIndex)` will translate `minIndex` (5) to `i,j`(1,2) array coordinates, i.e. 1st row, 2nd column in the array. I included an update on this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Well I looked into cellfun but didn't really grasp the idea behind it. If you can annotate the steps in the code you posted up there with a small explanation, I will be very grateful :)